# handling large timestamps when converting from pyarrow.Table to pandas

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, parquet, pyarrow

I have a timestamp of `9999-12-31 23:59:59` stored in a parquet file as an int96. I read this parquet file using pyarrow.dataset and convert the resulting table into a pandas dataframe (using pyarrow.Table.to_pandas()). The conversion to pandas dataframe turns my timestamp into `1816-03-30 05:56:07.066277376` (Pandas timestamp has probably smaller range of valid dates) without any complaing about datatype or anything.

I then take this pandas dataframe, convert it back to table and write it into a parquet dataset using pyarrow.dataset.write_dataset

I am now left with a different data than the data i started with, without seeing any warnings. (I found this out when I tried to create an impala table from the parquet dataset and then couldn't query it properly).

Is there a way to handle these large timestamps when converting from pyarrow table to pandas?

I've tried using the `timestamp_as_object = True` parameter as in  `Table.to_pandas(timestamp_as_object = True)`, but doesn't seem like it does anything.

**EDIT**: providing reproducible example. The problem is that pyarrow thinks the timestamps are nanoseconds while reading the file, although they were stored as microseconds:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
non_legacy_hdfs_filesystem = # connect to a filesystem here
my_table = pa.Table.from_arrays([pa.array(['9999-12-31', '9999-12-31', '9999-12-31']).cast('timestamp[us]')], names = ['my_timestamps'])
parquet_format = ds.ParquetFileFormat()
write_options = parquet_format.make_write_options(use_deprecated_int96_timestamps = True, coerce_timestamps = 'us', allow_truncated_timestamps = True)
ds.write_dataset(data = my_table, base_dir = 'my_path', filesystem = non_legacy_hdfs_filesystem, format = parquet_format, file_options = write_options, partitioning= None)

dataset = ds.dataset('my_path', filesystem = non_legacy_hdfs_filesystem)
dataset.to_table().column('my_timestamps')
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide some sample code? It's possible the error happens when converting from parquet to arrow (not from arrow to pandas).

Comment: Who would use a date like `9999-12-31 23:59:59`? To me, this looks like a "no value identifier". And yes, `pandas` datetime range is approx. year 1677 to 2262.

Comment: @0x26res you're right, actually already the pyarrow.Table shows the value of 1816-03-30 if i do table.column('my_column_name') and check the values in the chunked array. I'll try to figure out a code that generates such a problematic parquet file...

Comment: @MrFuppes I guess the author of the file wanted to indicate that if there is a missing value, the corresponding action will take place in an unknown time in future. As opposed to using the 1970-01-01 missing value identifier. Eitherway, i'd like to know how to work with such a file using pyarrow.

Comment: just from the Python/pandas side, you'll want this to be represented as `NaT` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#datetimes)), pandas' NaN for datetimes.

Comment: @0x26res so basically this code produces the same output as when i try to read the parquet file in our HDFS: `pa.array(['9999-12-31', '9999-12-31', '9999-12-31']).cast('timestamp[ns]')`. I.e. i get array of: `[
  1816-03-29 05:56:08.066277376,
  1816-03-29 05:56:08.066277376,
  1816-03-29 05:56:08.066277376
]`

Comment: I guess the problem is that my files contain timestamps in microseconds, while pyarrow tries to read them as nanoseconds. When I try to provide schema manually, it complains about `ArrowTypeError: fields had matching names but differing types. From: my_col: timestamp[ns] To:my_col: timestamp[ms]`

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that your data has been saved using `use_deprecated_int96_timestamps=True`.

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq


my_table = pa.Table.from_arrays([pa.array(['9999-12-31', '9999-12-31', '9999-12-31']).cast('timestamp[us]')], names = ['my_timestamps'])
pq.write_table(my_table, '/tmp/table.pq',  use_deprecated_int96_timestamps=True)
```

In this mode, timestamps are saved using 96 bits integer with a (default/hardcoded) nanosecond resolution.

```
>>> pq.read_metadata('/tmp/table.pq').schema[0]
<ParquetColumnSchema>
  name: my_timestamps
  path: my_timestamps
  max_definition_level: 1
  max_repetition_level: 0
  physical_type: INT96
  logical_type: None
  converted_type (legacy): NONE
```

In the latest version of arrow/parquet, timestamps are 64 bits integers with a configurable resolution.

It should be possible to convert the legacy 96 bits nano second timestamps to 64 bits integer using microsecond resolution without loss of information. But unfortunately there's no option in the [parquet reader](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.read_table.html#pyarrow.parquet.read_table) that would let you do that (as far as I can tell).

You may have to raise an issue with parquet/arrow, but I think they are trying hard to deprecate 96 bits integer[enter link description here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PARQUET-1883).

Comment: we are using older impala version unfortunately, so we do use int96 for our timestamps :(

Comment: I find it strange that it would be possible to store microsecond timestamps as int96 but then i couldn't read them...