# pyarrow/parquet saving large timestamp incorrectly

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, parquet, pyarrow

I've got some timestamps in a database that are `9999-12-31` and trying to convert to parquet. Somehow these timestamps all end up as `1816-03-29 05:56:08.066` in the parquet file.

Below is some code to reproduce the issue.

```
file_path = "tt.parquet"
schema = pa.schema([pa.field("tt", pa.timestamp("ms"))])
table = pa.Table.from_arrays([pa.array([datetime(9999, 12, 31),], pa.timestamp('ms'))], ["tt"])
writer = pq.ParquetWriter(file_path, schema)
writer.write_table(table)
writer.close()
```

I'm not trying to read the data with pandas but I've tried inspecting with pandas but that ends up with `pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Casting from timestamp[ms] to timestamp[ns] would result in out of bounds timestamp:` error.

I'm loading the parquet files into Snowflake and get back the incorrect timestamp. I've also tried inspecting with parquet-tools but that doesn't seem to work with timestamps.

Does parquet/pyarrow not support large timestamps? How can I store the correct timestamp?

Comment: Arrow stores timestamps as 64 bit integers with one of four resolutions (s, ms, us, ns).  The datetime 9999-12-31 will fit in s, ms, and us resolution but not ns resolution: https://gist.github.com/westonpace/54098651603b4ccfbe905acdd01d4f9c  Pandas only supports nanosecond timestamps.  That explains why you get an error when converting to Pandas.  I have no idea where 1816 is coming from.

Comment: I think 1816 comes from uncaught overflow in either writing the parquet file or  loading in snowflake.  Given the exception by the poster it seems Arrow is writing and reading back the value correctly and then failing to cast it.  So I would guess this is a snowflake issue.

Comment: With the code above (and reading back in the file), Arrow correctly roundtrips the date of 9999-12-31, so I assume it is indeed an issue on the snowflake side.

Comment: And if you want to convert the pyarrow.Table to a pandas DataFrame without running into the out of bounds issue, you can use `.to_pandas(timestamp_as_object=True)` to avoid trying to convert to pandas' nanosecond-resolution timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out for me, it was cause I needed to set `use_deprecated_int96_timestamps=False` on parquet [writer](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.write_table.html)

It says by default it's False but I had set the flavor to 'spark' so I think it overrode it.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Clearly the timestamp '9999-12-31' is being used not as a real timestamp, but as a flag for an invalid value.

If at the end of the pipeline Snowflake is seeing those as '1816-03-29 05:56:08.066', then you could just keep them as that - or re-cast them to whatever value you want them to have in Snowflake. At least it's consistent.

But if you insist that you want Python to handle the 9999 cases correctly, look at this question that solves it with `use_deprecated_int96_timestamps=True`:

- [handling large timestamps when converting from pyarrow.Table to pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66869968/handling-large-timestamps-when-converting-from-pyarrow-table-to-pandas)

Comment: The timestamp is being used as an end date, with this meaning there is no end date and is the current record. We are loading parquet into Snowflake without any transformations, the parquet file is storing the value `1816-03-29 05:56:08.066` somehow

Comment: So can you run an `UPDATE` of that date, once the data is loaded in Snowflake?